# How can I loop through a linked list and print each piece of data that matches the input?

Tags: java, loops, linked-list

I'm working on this method but am running into an issue. When I enter a word that matches the data in an index of the linked list, it only prints the first index of the Linked List the same number of times that the word I entered appears in the *entire* linked list.

```
public void iteratePrint(T aData) {
    if (head == null) {
        return;
    }
    //Typecast aData to string, and make it lowercase.
    String a = (String)aData;
    String strInput = a.toLowerCase();

    //Create temp listnode to loop through.
    ListNode temp =  head;
    
    //While temp is not null, check for match and if so, print.
    while(temp != null) {

        //Typecast temp.data into string (all of the data is a string anyway) and
        //Make sure it is lowercase.
        String b = (String)temp.data;
        String strTemp = b.toLowerCase();
        
        //This checks for the match and prints the current line.
        //Not currently working
        if(strTemp.contains(strInput)){
            System.out.println(temp.getCurrent());
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}
```

For example: The linked list contains these as String data  with their respective indices (balls bounce far, dogs play fetch with balls, my favorite toy is a ball). If I enter my input as "ball", I would like it to print out as

```
balls bounce far
dogs play fetch with balls
my favorite toy is a ball
```

However, it only prints out this:

```
balls bounce far
balls bounce far
balls bounce far
```

Ball appears 3 times, and it is only printing out the first index of the linked list the amount of times that the input appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `strTemp.contains(strInput)` is not satisfied `temp = temp.next;` will not get executed hence while loop will get stuck. Take `temp = temp.next;` outside of the if statement.

Comment: I just caught that! Thank you, It is now printing, however it is only printing the first index of the linked list the amount of times that the input shows up in the linked list. It seems like ```temp``` is not actually going to the next node.

Comment: @OMeihls Please provide the output

Comment: Check my original post for edits that show output

Comment: @OMeihls I see, I'll be able to help you if you put your LinkedList in the question

Comment: The LinkedList is incredibly long and would take up a very large amount of space in my post; I know that the program is reading it correctly, as it can print out the whole linked list through a separate print function. The only issue is the one that I have described. The problem is with the function I have, and that is what I am trying to solve.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved the issue. The problem was with my `getCurrent()` method. It was returning `current.data`, when I needed to return my `temp.data`. Thanks to everyone who helped! I appreciate it.